# attaching a plugin with live() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I coded for a div (`#div1`) that has a form (`#frm1`) with and attaches the [formWizard](http://thecodemine.org/#_demoForm=first) plugin to it. On click of a button outside of the div, a dialog is opened, with a button on click of which it reloads `#div1` using `$('#leftMenu').load('MainLeftMenu.jsp');`

The problem is that `#div1` gets reloaded with new values and the same plugin of `formWizard` is attached with the form but did not show the input boxes of the form, where as if I inspect the element they are in their respective positions.

I would like to have this working so that the new form (`#frm1`), coming from load, should get an attached formWizard plugin with it.

So, in summary, can I attach a third party plugin to a DOM element using live?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the formatting police. You are under arrest.

Comment: I think the way I wrote is quite good but anyway's I will keep the thing in mind thanks.............
:D

Comment: No, you cannot attach plugins to dom elements using live unless done with an event such as a click event.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.live` method is deprecated (use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) from now one). Have you considered activating the plugin on the new form in the [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method's callback?

```
$("#leftMenu").load("MainLeftMenu.jsp", function(){
    // At this point, your new elements are in the DOM
    $("#frm1", this).formwizard();
});
```

Comment: what's the second parameter **this** do in the call;

Comment: @ankur20us It provides context for the selector. It tells jQuery to find any `#frm1` in `this`, meaning, within `#leftMenu`. Do me a favor and use this: `$("#leftMenu").load("MainLeftMenu.jsp", function(){ console.log( arguments ); });` Tell me what it prints in your console.

Comment: @ankur20us Nothing in there has an id of "frm1". The only form element has an id of "frmAddChildLeftMenu".

Comment: Yeah I just gave an example, whatever you are saying I am changing it to the one I need.........

Comment: @ankur20us Can you give me a fresh look at your code so I can see how it looks right now?

Comment: shall we start in chat.....please [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11722/discussion-between-ankur20us-and-jonathan-sampson)